# jQuery selector for select elements with empty value attributes?

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-selectors

I'm using the below selector to get all the form inputs that are pre-populated with a value.

```
$('input[value!=""]');
```

This works great and so I thought I could apply the same logic to my select elements using the following selector, though it seems to be selecting all the select elements in Chrome.

```
$('select[value!=""]');
```

Below is an example of two types of selects on the form:

```
<select name="phone2_type" id="phone2_type">
  <option value="">Select one:</option>
  <option value="HOME">Home</option>
  <option value="CELL">Cell</option>
  <option value="BUSN">Business</option>
</select>

<select name="state" id="state">
  <option value="">Select one:</option>
  <option value="XX">Outside USA/Canada</option>
  <option value="AL" selected="selected">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  ...
</select>
```

I'd like to select the second select since it has a value selected already with the select="selected"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`value` is not an attribute of `select` tag.

So you need to try:

```
var emptySelect = $('select').filter(function() {
                     return $.trim( $(this).val() ) == '';
                  });
```

Comment: Easy, clean and straight-forward. Not to mention that it works for `input` as well.

Answer (score 2):

For select you need to use a special selector made available by JQuery: :selected

So

```
$('#state option:selected').val()
```

is the current selected value.

If you need the do something on the *select* elements themself you could do something like:

```
$('#select option:selected').parents('select').dosomething(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('select').has('option[selected="selected"]')
```

will get the select element. **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2hNAb/)**.

Comment: This doesn't work in FF for dinamically added selects. It's a known bug. That's why JQuery added _:selected_ which uses (i think) _.selectedIndex_ attribute of the select element

Comment: @PaoloCasciello - Where does the OP mention dynamically added selects?

Comment: You're right but he doesn't mention the browser too.. ;) Let's write the most useful answer. :)

Comment: Both were very helpful. I'm giving it to j08691 since he posted first, though I'm glad you pointed out the issue with dynamically added selects @Paolo Casciello