# .focus() not working after calling a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Can anyone please explain why the focus command works properly if the alert( is enabled but doesn't work when I use my errmsgPopper function (as the code is now)?

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function(){
  // Register a new user
  $(document).on('click', '#Register', function(evnt) {
    if (userName == "" || password == "" || emailAddress == "") {
//      alert("Complete all the input fields");
      errmsgPopper("Complete all the input fields");
      // This next line works correctly if the alert( is used instead of the
      //  errmsgPopper function above
      $('input:text[value=""], input:password[value=""]').first().focus();
      evnt.stopImmediatePropagation();
      return false;
    }
  });

  // Popup error message for 2 seconds
  function errmsgPopper(msg){
    $('#errmsgDiv').html(msg).popup('open', {
      positionTo: $('input:text[value=""], input:password[value=""]').first()
    });
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('#errmsgDiv').popup('close');
    },2000);
  }

  // Save the User name
  $(document).on('blur', '#UserName', function(evnt) {
    var $target = $(evnt.target); 
    userName = $target.val();
  });

  // Save their password
  $(document).on('blur', '#Password', function(evnt) {
    var $target = $(evnt.target); 
    password = $target.val();
  });

  // Save their email address
  $(document).on('blur', '#EmailAddress', function(evnt) {
    var $target = $(evnt.target); 
    emailAddress = $target.val();
  });

});
```

The HTML:

```
  <div id="LoginPage" data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header"><h1>Login to ECG</h1>
      <a id="LoginClick" href="#LoginSubmit" title="Submit login details">Submit</a>
      <a id="Register" href="#LoginPage" align="right" title="Register new user">Register</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
      <form>
        <div>
          <label for="UserName">User name</label>
          <input id="UserName" title="Enter your User Name" tabindex="1" type="text" placeholder="User name" maxlength="10" autofocus>
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="Password">Password</label>
          <input id="Password" title="Enter your Password" tabindex="2" type="password" placeholder="Password" maxlength="10">
        </div>
        <div>
          <label for="EmailAddress">Email address</label>
          <input id="EmailAddress" title="Enter your email address" tabindex="3" type="text" placeholder="Email address" maxlength="40">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <div data-role="footer"><h1>Educational card games</h1>
      <a href="#" title="Retrieve your password">Lost PW</a>
    </div>

  </div>
```

errmsgDiv:

```
  <div id="errmsgDiv" data-role="popup"><p>msg text</p></div>
```

I didn't set up a fiddle yet as I suspect there is a simple answer...

Comment: alert is a predefined java script statement (method). while jquery is not as old as java script it may contain some bugs. this is probably one of them.

Comment: Make a jsfiddle with a working example. Currently your variables aren't even being defined.

Comment: OK, I'll do that but it's late here now so it won't be today. I have a suspician that the .focus() IS working and that this has something to do with the timeout. I will do a bit more experimentation before I set up the fiddle. There are only three variables and these are setup when each input field blurs so there's no rocket science there. Since the logic works fine when using the alert I can't imagine that it can be a coding issue, but it may be a scope issue?

Comment: you cant have both working at same time, popup and focus on page. Page loses focus once a popup is open.

Comment: Change `errmsgPopper` to take a callback so you can pass in a function to do your focus *after* the popup has closed.

Comment: I forgot to ask you whether you're using jQM 1.4 or earlier version.

Comment: jquery.mobile-1.3.1 @Omar Is that bad?

Comment: Well, jQM has more features now and has fixed 1.3 bugs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When *popup* is active, page loses focus as well as any element inside it. Alternatively, you can `focus()` after popup is hidden/closed.

Modify `setTimeout` to focus on `popupafterclose` event.

```
setTimeout(function () {
  $('#errmsgDiv').popup({
    afterclose: function () {
      $("input[value='']").first().focus();
    }
  }).popup("close");
}, 2000);
```

Also, you need to manually *initialize* the *external* popup.

```
$(function () {
  $("#errmsgDiv").popup();
});
```

#### Update

I have used this [little snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14942622/1771795) <sup>(1)</sup> to determine *empty fields* and then `focus()` on first one.

```
var checkEmpty = $('form input').filter(function () {
  return $.trim($(this).val()) == '';
});
```

This will return an object of all empty fields, pick `.first()` one to position popup and focus.

#### Full code

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function () {
    var checkEmpty; /* global */
    $(document).on('click', '#Register', function (evnt) {
        checkEmpty = $('form input').filter(function () {
            return $.trim($(this).val()) == '';
        });
        if ($("#UserName").val() == "" || $("#Password").val() == "" || $("#EmailAddress").val() == "") {
            errmsgPopper("Complete all the input fields");
            return false;
        }
    });

    function errmsgPopper(msg) {
        $('#errmsgDiv').html(msg).popup('open', {
            positionTo: $(checkEmpty).first()
        });
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#errmsgDiv').popup({
                afterclose: function () {
                    $(checkEmpty).first().focus();
                }
            }).popup("close");
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/nV6pF/)**

<sup>(1) Credit to [@thecodeparadox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/690854/thecodeparadox)</sup>

Comment: Yes Omar, this is neater but I haven't managed to make it work properly yet. It always returns focus to the first input field regardless of which is the first empty input field. (I do initialise the popup, but forgot to include it in my code above. Excuse me.)

Comment: @cneeds I have changed the selector of empty input. I'll check it and let you know.

Comment: No worries Omar, I got it working. I need to put in some logic to either focus on the first empty input or the input with an error (like the email address) to make the function work for all possible error conditions. But yours is definitely the neater solution. Thank you.

Comment: @cneeds I'm glad it worked for you. I just logged in to test my solution thoroughly.

Comment: @cneeds I've updated my fiddle. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without more information, this is kind of a guess, but try:

```
function errmsgPopper(msg, callback){
    $('#errmsgDiv').html(msg).popup('open', {
        positionTo: $('input:text[value=""], input:password[value=""]').first()
    });
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#errmsgDiv').popup('close');
        if (callback && typeof callback === "function") {
            callback();
        }
    },2000);
}
```

And then you'd change your call to this:

```
errmsgPopper("Complete all the input fields", function() { 
    $('input:text[value=""], input:password[value=""]').first().focus();
});
```

Now your focus will only get changed after the popup has closed.

Comment: Thank you Matt, almost there. The first input without a value does get the focus in that my onfocus css triggers but the cursor doesn't become active so I still have to click it to be able to type in it... ?

Comment: OK, I moved the evnt.stopImmediatePropagation(); statement into the callback function (though I don't think it's needed anymore?) and it works perfectly. Thank you