# Capture the ID of first visible empty form element on a page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to capture the ID of the first visible empty form element on a page. This approach captures text fields, but is there a more general way for options, radio button, checkbox, etc?

```
var lastfieldsid = $("input[value='']:visible:first").attr("id");
  alert(lastfieldsid)
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/meq27wse/)

Comment: Not really, because checkboxes are toggle states, so there's no real way to tell if they are "empty" or just "off". You could try `:not(:checked)`, but that would also find elements that the user unticked. Selectboxes always have an option selected, so there you would have to see if the selected option is the "select an option" placeholder, an option that just like all others is valid.

Comment: The "please select" value of an option listbox (as shown in my demo) is always null therefor alerting the user to select an option if its required.

Comment: Offtopic: if you're looking for the *first* element using `:first` - why is your variable name *last*fieldsid ?

Comment: Not a complete answer: you can combine multiple selections, then apply the `:visible` after, eg: `$("input[value=''],checkbox:not(:checked)").is(":visible").first()` but there's no "1 selector fits all" option as each input type has its own method to find if it's got a value, eg for a select you have to use `.has`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14942677/2181514

Comment: originally i was testing last field. thankfully i didn't make that mistake with my question